# How does the `extending` method work in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I don't understand how this method works in this case:

```
def self.page(page)
  limit(default).offset(page * default).extending do
  def per(num)
    limit(num).offset(page * num)
  end
end
```

It is a little bit different from [the original code](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/models/active_record_model_extension.rb).

We can use `ModelName.page(1).per(5)`. I am really confused regarding how it works. Looks like some magic happened.

Comment: from where you found the code you mentioned in your question ?

Comment: Check the link in my question. My code is a simple version of the original. From kaminari gem.

Comment: Please _notify_ me if you don't understand any part still.. I'll try to help you.,.

Comment: I added a comment below your answer. Does it work similarly with the singleton class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [extending](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/extending) saying -

> Used to extend a scope with additional methods, either through a module or through a block provided. The object returned is a relation, which can be further extended.

Here is an little example to illustrate this functionality:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  def self.scope_cart
    self.where(currency: "INR").extending do
      def orders_in_cart
        where.not(state: 'cart')
      end
    end
  end
end

Spree::Order.scope_cart.count # => 367
# SQl code
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "spree_orders"  WHERE "spree_orders"."currency" = 'INR'
Spree::Order.count # => 367
```

Till now, you can see that the `scope_cart` is giving me the data count which is the result from `self.where(currency: "INR")`. Well, let's see now what the new method `orders_in_cart` gives us.

```
Spree::Order.scope_cart.orders_in_cart.count # => 342
# SQL code
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "spree_orders"  WHERE "spree_orders"."currency" = 'INR' AND ("spree_orders"."state" != 'cart')
```

**Note :** Please *note* the **SQL** code, for 2 different cases. There is the answer of your question.

Now coming to your example again. When you will call `ModelName.page(1)`, you will get the result of this `limit(default).offset(page * default)`. Now if you want the additional filtering, you will call `per` method as `ModelName.page(1).per(5)`, then you will get the result from `limit(num).offset(page * num)`, which is **applied** on the result of `limit(default).offset(page * default)`.

Extending it further more :

When you do `ModelName.page(1)`, `limit` is taking the **default** per value, with `offset` as `1 * default`. Equivalent *SQL* is -

```
SELECT  "model_names".* FROM "model_names"  LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20
```

When you do `ModelName.page(1).per(5)`, `limit` is taking the `5` as per value, with `offset` as `1 * 5`.  Equivalent SQL is -

```
SELECT  "model_names".* FROM "model_names"  LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

In Rails, I saw in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-limit) if you write like `User.limit(10).limit(20)`, it generates SQL has `LIMIT 20`, means it take the **last** `limit` clause in the chain. Same is `true` for the `offset`.

Look the console generated **SQL** code :

```
Spree::Order.limit(20).offset(2).limit(5).offset(5)
# Spree::Order Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders"  LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

Comment: So, we can use this method for a Relation only, and the result will be a relation. Is it same with ``result = Spree::Order.limit(3)\n class << result\n def per(num)....``

Comment: @duykhoa No it is mostly like [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-extend).

Comment: Understand, it's an advance usage. But it looks pretty awesome.